# Парсинг json на php

Tags: php, json

Доброго времени суток всем.
Есть ответ на запрос из твиттера

```
 $json = json_decode($output, true);
```

он содержит массив дынных о новостях пользователя

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [created_at] => Thu May 07 07:21:45 +0000 2015
        [id] => 596213314683830272
        [id_str] => 596213314683830272
        [text] => Поздравляем с Великим Праздником – Днем Победы! http://t.co/kNDt37qyEc
        [source] => 
[truncated] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 242351516
                    [id_str] => 242351516
                    [name] => Element Store
                    [screen_name] => ElementStore
                    [location] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [url] => http://t.co/setDyQlBD0
                    [entities] => Array
                        (
                            [url] => Array
                                (
                                    [urls] => Array
                                        (
```

и так далее, очень много данных.
Из всего этого нужно слепить новостную ленту на сайте.
Пробовал так,

```
foreach ($json as $tweet) { 
        echo '<div style="margin-left:50px;">';
        foreach ($tweet as $t => $value) {
            echo '<span>'.$t.'</span> <b>'.$value['text'].'</b><br>';
            foreach ($value as $key => $value2) {
                echo '<span>'.$key.'</span> <b>'.$value2['url'].'</b><br>';
            }
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

И вот так

```
foreach ($json as $tweet) { 
        echo '<div style="margin-left:50px;">';
        foreach ($tweet as $t => $value) {
            echo '<span>'.$t.'</span> <b>'.$value->text.'</b><br>';
            foreach ($value as $key => $value2) {
                echo '<span>'.$key.'</span> <b>'.$value2->url.'</b><br>';
            }
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

Получается фигня, что я делаю не так? 
[фигня которая получается](http://codepen.io/StadnikovP/pen/vOLEgv), а фигня это потому что мне нужны только конкретные поля, например [text] и [user][url], а тут выводятся все подряд.

Comment: Неплохо было бы написать что за "фигня" у вас получается на выходе, и почему вы считаете её именно "фигней"

Comment: [то что получается](http://codepen.io/StadnikovP/pen/vOLEgv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
foreach ($json as $tweet) 
{ 
    echo '<div style="margin-left:50px;">';
    echo '<b>'.$tweet['text'].'</b><br>';
    echo '<a href='.$tweet['user']['url'].'>'.$tweet['user']['name'].'</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Если я правильно понял, то вам незачем выводить ключи массивов

`echo '<span>'.$t.'</span> ....`  ,   `echo '<span>'.$key.'</span> ....`

И потом проходить циклом по параметрам value

Comment: Вы совершенно правильно поняли, спасибо большое! Оно работает!!